# How to set aggregate bit value for a group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to "roll up" bit values for a group in my table via an `UPDATE`. So if one row in the group has a bit set to true, I need to set other rows in the group to true.

For example, I have a table like this:

```
GroupID | Type   | BitA | BitB
------------------------------
   1    | Parent |  0   |  0
   1    | Child  |  1   |  0
   2    | Parent |  0   |  0
   2    | Child  |  1   |  1
   2    | Child  |  0   |  1
   3    | Parent |  0   |  0
   3    | Child  |  0   |  0
```

The expected result after the `UPDATE` statement would then be:

```
GroupID | Type   | BitA | BitB
------------------------------
   1    | Parent |  1   |  0
   1    | Child  |  1   |  0
   2    | Parent |  1   |  1
   2    | Child  |  1   |  1
   2    | Child  |  0   |  1
   3    | Parent |  0   |  0
   3    | Child  |  0   |  0
```

Since Group 1 has a Child with BitA set to true, the Parent should also be set to true.

The only thing I've been able to find is casting the bit as an int first in order to aggregate it in the group, but it seems like I'm going down a rabbit hole.:

```
SELECT
   MAX(CAST(BitA as int)),
   MAX(CAST(BitB as int))
FROM MyTable
WHERE Type = 'Child'
GROUP BY GroupID
```

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: I don't follow the logic.  Are you trying to rollup the values?  Or are you comparing all rows within the group?

Comment: I'm trying to rollup the values from the Child records to the Parent record. Basically, if any Child has a bit value set to true, the Parent should also get set to true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want to set the parent flags based on the children:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             max(BitA) over (partition by groupid) as max_bitA,
             max(BitB) over (partition by groupid) as max_bitB
      from mytable t
     )
update toupdate
    set BitA = max_BitA,
        BitB = max_BitB
    where BitA <> max_BitA or BitB <> max_BitB;
```

If your bits are really typed as `bit`, you need some conversions:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             convert(bit, max(convert(int, BitA)) over (partition by groupid)) as max_bitA,
             convert(bit, max(convert(int, BitB)) over (partition by groupid)) as max_bitB
      from mytable t
     )
update toupdate
    set BitA = max_BitA,
        BitB = max_BitB
    where BitA <> max_BitA or BitB <> max_BitB;
```

Answer (score 0):

this could give you what you need ...

```
UPDATE M1
SET M1.BITA = 1,
    M1.BITB = 1
FROM MYTABLE M1
WHERE EXISTS
(
SELECT 1
  FROM MYTABLE M2
 WHERE M2.GroupID = M1.GoupID
      AND
     (
        M2.BITA = 1
       OR M2.BITB = 1
  )
);
```